# find and replace variable with variable

Tags: linux, shell

- step1: get values from source and target (s.xml,t.xml) in some file T_XML_PFILE.log >> this is achieved check point 1*
- step2: replace the source file s.xml with target using variables from T_XML_PFILE.log >> to be done point 2*

source: cat s.xml

```
      <global_db_name oa_var="s_dbSid">PEBS2SIT</global_db_name>
      <db_name_lower oa_var="s_dbSidLower">pebs2sit</db_name_lower>
```

target: cat t.xml

```
cat t.xml
      <global_db_name oa_var="s_dbSid">PEBSPAT</global_db_name>
      <db_name_lower oa_var="s_dbSidLower">pebspat</db_name_lower>
```

point 1: command to extract values from source and target

```
T_PDBNAME_C=`awk -F "[><]" '/"s_dbSid"/{print $3}' $T_FILE`" >T_XML_PFILE.log
T_PDBNAME_S=`awk -F "[><]" '/s_dbSidLower/{print $3}' $T_FILE`">>T_XML_PFILE.log
S_PDBNAME_C=`awk -F "[><]" '/"s_dbSid"/{print $3}' $S_FILE`" >>T_XML_PFILE.log
S_PDBNAME_S=`awk -F "[><]" '/s_dbSidLower/{print $3}' $S_FILE`" >>T_XML_PFILE.log
```

```
cat T_XML_PFILE.log
T_PDBNAME_C=PEBSPAT
T_PDBNAME_S=pebspat

S_PDBNAME_C=PEBS2SIT
S_PDBNAME_S=pebs2sit
```

point 2:action required is replace source with target value and get output as below:

```
cat s.xml
      <global_db_name oa_var="s_dbSid">PEBSPAT</global_db_name>
      <db_name_lower oa_var="s_dbSidLower">pebspat</db_name_lower>
```

Comment: You must use `"` if you want your variables expanded. `'` prevents variable expansion

Comment: Hello Knittl i used all above but gettin error like sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular

Comment: How do you define your variables to be used by sed? The expected output does not match the (expected?) sed expressions. The value of `S_PDBNAME_C` is "PEBS2SIT", not "PEBSPAT". Are you simply trying the remove everything and include the "=" character? `cut -d= -f2-` will do that

Comment: let me re-phrase, i have some file of say 2k lines on source of which few variables are to be replaced and create new file same as source but with new values ex: for all occurance of $S_PDBNAME_C to be replaced by $T_PDBNAME_C and file name to be renames as target. that piece i extracted
T_PDBNAME_C=PEBSPAT
T_PDBNAME_S=pebspat
..
..
S_PDBNAME_C=PEBS2SIT
S_PDBNAME_S=pebs2sit 
.. 
..
i need replace command to change that in source file. please help rgds R Syed

Comment: I still find it difficult to grok the question. Can you reduce the text and code to 2-3 lines to make it more obvious? Can you share the definition of your variables? Or do you have a text file that contains what looks like variable assignments and you want to evaluate these assigments?

Comment: Hello Knittl,Please check my comment in main section this window is too small to update. regards R Syed

Comment: Using syntax-unaware tools to edit XML is failure-prone. Use real XML-aware tools for this; awk is not well-suited to the job, and any awk script you write will fail with different, equally-valid encodings of the same document.

Comment: And the variables only exist in the text file? They are not real shell variables? Can you fix those awk lines? They contain syntax errors (mismatched quotes) and currently do not produce the log file given. (Are you missing `echo`?)

Comment: cat code.sh
```
echo "T_PDBNAME_C=`awk -F "[><]" '/"s_dbSid"/{print $3}' $T_FILE`" >T_XML_PFILE.log
echo "S_PDBNAME_C=`awk -F "[><]" '/"s_dbSid"/{print $3}' $S_FILE`" >>T_XML_PFILE.log
sed -i'.bak' "s/$S_PDBNAME_C/$T_PDBNAME_C/g" $S_FILE
sed -i'.bak' "s/$S_PDBNAME_S/$T_PDBNAME_S/g" $S_FILE
```

error:
+ sed -i.bak s///g s.xml
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
+ sed -i.bak s///g s.xml
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Comment: Hello Team, can any one help to fix the code issue. regards R Syed